# Un-tar a specific directory inside of a tar

Tags: linux, wordpress, directory, tar

I have the Wordpress tar, latest.tar.gz.  Within it is the following structure
/wordpress/dirtories/files

When I do the following command I would prefer if I could have it unpack starting at /directories/ and not /wordpress with the goal of installing wordpress in the root of my html directory.

tar -xzvf latest.tar.gz

Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

Sorry, the tar contains /wordpress/[Directories] and I want all the directories in [Directories] extracted to the current directory.  Sorry for misleading you all.

Comment: --strip is unrecognized on the server that Im on.  Looking for an answer still.

Comment: My version of tar is 1.13.25 btw.

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35311/how-do-you-extract-a-single-folder-from-a-large-tar-gz-archive)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To strip down the parent directory:

```
tar zxvf latest.tar.gz --strip 1
```

If you want to be sure that nothing from the parent directory is extracted:

```
tar zxvf latest.tar.gz --strip 1 wordpress/directories
```

**Edit:**

`--strip` (`--strip-path` or `--strip-components`) was introduced in tar 1.14.

Comment: I unchecked this as the answer because for some reason --strip isn't recognized.  Any advice would be great.

Comment: tar 1.14 was released over five years ago...surprising that some people don't have it yet

Answer (score 0):

tar xvzf file.tar.gz -C /extract/point/

Comment: This does not do what I asked.  Within the tar there is a root directory, I don't want that extracted, just everything under it.

Answer (score 0):

```
tar -xvzf file.tar.gz wordpress/*
```

will extract all the subdirectories (and files) of the wordpress folder into the current directory by creating a wordpress subdirectory.  One way to "fool" the extraction by doing

```
ln -s . wordpress
```

and then running the tar extraction.  The result will create each subfolder in the current folder because you linked the wordpress directory to the current directory.

Afterwards you can remove the wordpress symbolic link as it is no longer needed.

Comment: This is looking good.  But the tar file has Wordpress/[LotsOfDirectories].  I'm updating my question.  So, I want all the directories after Wordpress/ to be extracted and it looks like this sym link trick I would have to create a link for each of those directories?  Is there another way?

Comment: You should be able to use wordpress/* just as effectively as wordpress/directories and the symlink will still work since you're only trying to "redirect" the top level wordpress